# How to add featured grid column in category section just after position

Tags: category-products, featured-product

I want to add a featured column just after position column in the following section

```
Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Category Products
```

This column should have checkboxes. The products for which checkboxes are checked will be considered as featured products for that specific category and will be listed in the frontend.

Any help or clue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add the new column, you will need to override the Core Block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product` 
that lists the products in the category
You can use the same method as `Position` column

`$this->addColumn('position', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
            'width'     => '1',
            'type'      => 'number',
            'index'     => 'position',
            'editable'  => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
            //'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_input'
        ));`

You will need to change the 'index' and `editable`

And add an attribute called `featured` in the product

Comment: This way I can only make a checkboxes column visible in the backend. Data will not be saved. I have already tried this. It is not working for me.

Comment: You can add an observer for category save event, and save the data from observer

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's a common way to think of featured being an attribute of a product, but if all you want is create a collection of featured products, then think of that collection as a category.

For the backend there's little difference in workflow and you don't need custom attribute and code. All the tools to render such a category can be done in layout XML, including the homepage.

This message is sponsored by the KISS foundation. ;-)